# how to delete value of one dropdown when the other dropdown value is selected and vice versa?

Tags: plotly-dash

I have two dropdown menu using dcc.Dropdown(). If I select one a value from a dropdown menu, I'd like to de-select anything on the other dropdown menu and Vice Versa.

here is what I did to define two callbacks, with each callback to set the value of the other dropdown value to empty when one dropdown value is selected. I got an error of circular dependency error. Thanks for your help.

for example, I have two dropdown, dts-filename-dropdown and dts-longterm-filename-dropdown.

```
@app.callback(
    [
    Output("dts-filename-dropdown", "value")
    ],
    [
     Input("dts-longterm-filename-dropdown", "value")
    ],
)
def close_tfo_dts_filename(dts_longterm_filename):
    if dts_longterm_filename is not None:
        dts_filename=[]
        return dts_filename
    else:  
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
        
        
@app.callback(
    [
    Output("dts-longterm-filename-dropdown", "value")
    ],
    [
     Input("dts-filename-dropdown", "value")
    ],
)
def close_longterm_dts_filename(dts_longterm_filename):
    if dts_filename is not None:
        dts_longterm_filename=[]
        return dts_longterm_filename
    else:  
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [circular callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#circular-callbacks) where the inputs and outputs are identical. Here is an example for your case:

```py
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("dts-longterm-filename-dropdown", "value"),
        Output("dts-filename-dropdown", "value")
    ],
    [
        Input("dts-longterm-filename-dropdown", "value"),
        Input("dts-filename-dropdown", "value"),
    ],
)
def close_longterm_dts_filename(dts_longterm_filename, dts_filename):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        button_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
        if button_id == "dts-filename-dropdown":
            return [], dts_filename
        else:
            return dts_longterm_filename, []
```